Enable chrome extension automation anywhere 360 extension Programmatically
I'm getting a chrome plug in issue most of the time when running Automation anywhere and it's showing that extension is not enabled. I need a code help to enable plugin/extension programmatically using C#. can anyone help me on this?

You can't directly enable chrome extension because of chrome security police(After Chrome 25).
